# Handling failed task in Yocto recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I need some advice on how to handle errors in recipe tasks. Consider the following snippet for a Yocto recipe recipe:

```
do_compile_custom() {
    oe_runmake  // oe_runmake command fails 
}
addtask compile_custom after do_compile before do_install
```

When `oe_runmake` fails, i want to execute some custom command and to continue with the build so i thought that this should work.

```
do_compile_custom() {
    oe_runmake || true // oe_runmake command fails 
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        bberror "MAKE FAILED"
    fi
}
addtask compile_custom after do_compile before do_install
```

But when `oe_runmake` fails, it exits the task and the rest of the task is not executed. I don't see

> MAKE FAILED

in my build log.

I started to investigate bitbake Events so the next thing i did was to add an event handler in my recipe, without any event filters at first to see all the events received.

```
do_compile_custom() {
    oe_runmake  // oe_runmake command fails 
}
addtask compile_custom after do_compile before do_install

addhandler failure_eventhandler
python failure_eventhandler() {
    from bb.event import getName
    print("strtogrep The name of the Event is %s" % getName(e))
}
```

With this implementation of the recipe, from the handler i am only able to see 3 events printed:

```
| The name of the Event is RecipePreFinalise
| The name of the Event is RecipeTaskPreProcess
| The name of the Event is RecipeParsed
```

From all the events defined in bitbake, i was expecting to get `TaskFailed` Event after the task fails but this is never received. Does anyone have some suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why You can't occur **MAKE FAILES** log message is the consequence of *oe_runmake* function.

As You can see implementation of *oe_runmake* (from *meta/classes/base.bbclass* file), runs **die()** logging function in case of any failures:

```
58 oe_runmake() {                                     
59     oe_runmake_call "$@" || die "oe_runmake failed"
60 }
```

Lately on *die()* function use *bbfatal_log()* function (from *meta/classes/logging.bbclass* file), which finally end's with **exit 1**:

```
66 bbfatal_log() {
67     if [ -p ${LOGFIFO} ] ; then
68         printf "%b\0" "bbfatal_log $*" > ${LOGFIFO}
69     else
70         echo "ERROR: $*"
71     fi
72     exit 1
73 }
```

I think easiest way for You to archive Your goal, is to give up with using default *do_compile* implementation task in order that have a custom compile task, with error handling:

```
# disable do_compile task
do_compile[noexec] = "1"

do_compile_custom() {
    oe_runmake_custom_call() {                    
        bbnote ${MAKE} ${EXTRA_OEMAKE} "$@"
        ${MAKE} ${EXTRA_OEMAKE} "$@"       
    }                                      

    oe_runmake_custom_call || bbwarn "oe_runmake_custom failed"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        bberror "MAKE FAILED"
    fi
}
addtask compile_custom before do_install
```

Comment: This works for me but i still would like to know why are the events not working

Answer (score 2):

Why not override the die function so that it will check an env-var for action?

```
die_action ??= "bbfatal_log"
die() {
  ${die_action} "$*"
}
```

You could define that in your own no-die.bbclass which you inherit with:

```
INHERIT += "no-die'
```

in a global config file, or perhaps in a recipe

```
inherit no-die
```

And then somewhere else, perhaps in a recipe or class:

```
fixup() {
  bbwarn "Didn't Die: $*"
}
```

and then

```
die_action="fixup"
```

I've not tested this